# change popup submenu dropDown title color

Tags: android, popupmenu

I'm using default poupMenu, I have customized my popup menu to a dark theme, now I want to know that how can I change popup submenu title color in my theme?

This is my styles:

```
    <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <!-- <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-4dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4dp</item>-->
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/material_grey_900</item>
</style>
<style name="popup_TextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/color_item_popup</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/popup_text_size</item>
</style>
```

And I'm using it in my theme like this:

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/popup_TextStyle</item>
```

This is the view of my popup menu:

[image: image description]

Now I need to change the title color(#FF4081).

Comment: Can you demonstrate how do you show the `PopupMenu`, the actual and desired behaviors via screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it programmatically with below code, If anyone interested:

```
// Change PopupMenu subMenu title color
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, view);
Menu itemSetAs = popup.getMenu();
SubMenu s = itemSetAs.findItem(R.id.setAsRingtone).getSubMenu();
SpannableString headerTitle = new SpannableString(itemSetAs.findItem(R.id.setAsRingtone).getTitle());
headerTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YOUR_COLOR), 0, headerTitle.length(), 0);
s.setHeaderTitle(headerTitle);
```

*I've Tested it myself.*